# Trying to use granger causality. Not sure how to interpret output

Tags: r, time-series

I have two sets of time series data,

- Number of visitors to a zoo `[6826   500  2050  5353    79    27    22    89   123   228  1647  1541   290   296 .....]`
- Weather conditions data(precipitation, 1/0 variables for rain, snowfall, mist etc.) `[0  86  41   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 196   0   0  43  18   0   8  23  38   0  58 .....]`

I'm trying to test for granger causality to determine the effect of weather data on visitor counts using the `lmtest` package in R.

In the below code, I'd tested for precipitation data.

```
 grangertest(dayvisitors ~ prec, order = 5)
    grangertest(prec ~ dayvisitors, order = 5)
```

For the first test, the p-value was 0.00153208 and for the second, the p-value was even more significant: 1.861e-05.

If I understand correctly this means there is some exogenous variable, z that could be a better candidate for testing causation. But this doesn't make sense in this context because there cannot be a variable that could have a causal effect on the weather data. And previous values for visitor counts helping predict weather data also doesn't make sense.

Can somebody help me interpret this?

Comment: Granger causality is not causality! It just assess whether one variable can be predicted by lags of another variable. This is well possible for your data: after days of bad weather visitors might go to the zoo on subsequent days. Or if they have seen bad weather forecasts, they might do their visit a couple of days earlier. Or there is some confounder as you write...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I understand its not actually causality, sorry I used that term loosely in my post. Is there any way to quantify the relationship after it turns out the be significant in test? I mean, now that I know 5 lags of precipitation can be used to predict my visitor count, is there a way to find out how much each of those lags influence the predicted value?

Comment: Internally the function just sets up a linear regression of one variable on the lags of the other variable. You can easily do the same and look at the R-squared or any other quantity you are interested in.

Comment: @ChandruGopalakrishnan like Achim said in his comment. Granger Causality is a linear regression with one lag of the dependent variable and the sum of independent variable lags. If you set the lags you will use, you can fir a linear model `lm` and use `summary` to get into details. However, the method that GC uses retains only the significant lags up until the maximum lags you have set before (or selected by AIC,BIC....etc). Since the null hypothesis in CG is (x does not granger cause y) and the above p-values, you can reject that hypothesis and accept the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Have you though about people checking the weather forcast and deciding wether or not to go to the zoo. That could explain a "causal" relationship... Moreover, check if the error terms are auto-correlated for the two variables that you are using and the number of lags using the `serial.test` function.